# How do I broadcast a message to a specific URL using JavaScript and Flask_socketio?

Tags: javascript, python, flask-socketio

I am building an online messaging service (similar in spirit to Slack) and I want to see the broadcast messages only when I am visiting the URL where the message has been posted. Currently, a message is sent to all the channels (URLs).

I have tried to add a namespace :

```
@socketio.on('submit message', namespace='/channel/0')
```

but no message go through.

I have also tried to add '/channel/0' info to the socket

```
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/channel/0');
```

but the message would still be sent to channel/1 as well.

```
@app.route("/channel/<int:channel_id>")
def channel(channel_id):
    channel_name = channels[channel_id]
    messages = chat_messages[channel_id]
return render_template('channel.html', channel_name=channel_name, messages=messages, channel_id=channel_id)

@socketio.on('submit message')
def chat(data):
    # Retrieve data from form
    display_name = data['display_name']
    content_typed = data['content_typed']
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    channel_id = int(data['channel_id'])

    # Add message to list
    chat_messages[channel_id].append( {'display_name' : display_name,'content_typed':content_typed,
     'timestamp': timestamp } )

    # Display last message
    emit("All messages", chat_messages[channel_id][-1], broadcast=True)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// connect to websocket
        var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

 // when connected configure submit button to submit new messages
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            document.querySelector('#form_channel').onsubmit = () => {
                const content_typed = document.querySelector('#message').value;
                const display_name = localStorage.getItem('user');
                const channel_id = document.querySelector('#channel_id').value;
                socket.emit('submit message', {'display_name' : display_name,'content_typed':content_typed,'channel_id': channel_id});
                document.querySelector('#message').value = '';

                return false;
            };

            return false;
        });

        // // When a new message is created, add to the unordered list
        socket.on('All messages', data => {
            const p = document.createElement('p')
            p.innerHTML = `from ${data.display_name} on ${data.timestamp}: ${data.content_typed} `;
            document.querySelector('#chatroom').append(p)
        })
    });
```

When a user send a message while visiting the channel/0 URL, I only want to see it on this URL not in others (for example : channel/1). If I refresh the page the message will be correctly stored to the proper route, the issue is with the broadcasting.

Comment: I'm confused about how you are associating URLs with Socket.IO events. They are completely independent of each other, a Socket.IO connection works on its own private endpoint, no application URLs are involved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by creating 2 different sockets: one that communicate with all the channels and another one that only send the message to the channel is has been emitted from.

```
@socketio.on('submit message')
def chat(data):
    # Retrieve data from socket

    # Add message to list

    # Display last message
    emit("All messages", chat_messages[channel_id][-1], namespace=f'/channel/{channel_id}', broadcast=True)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        var channel_id = document.querySelector('#channel_id').value;
        var socket2 = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + `/channel/${channel_id}`);
...
socket2.on('All messages', data => {
            ...
        });
}
```